# Javscript search function working sporadically

Tags: javascript, html, css, .htaccess

I have a simple search feature on the products page of my hi fi business. I am somewhat of a rookie developer and have spliced SaaS for the products repository and inserted HTML/CSS/JS, too.

It sometimes works, it sometimes doesn't.

What I have noticed is that when I strike enter to search for the item, the URL for the product appears in the address bar, but it doesn't load the page. Console and sources (opera) aren't showing any errors.

Here's some of my code:

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum- 
scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<title>Tuto</title>
</head>


<body style=" background-color: rgb(4, 41, 255);">

<input type="search" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="Search here..." id="search" 
onchange="openPage()">

<script>
function openPage() {
var x = document.getElementById("search").value;

if (x.toLowerCase() === "Wave".toLowerCase()) {
window.top.location = ("/Products#!/products/wave-usb---dealer-only---click-for-more-info");
}
        
if (x.toLowerCase() === "Wave USB".toLowerCase()) {
window.top.location = ("/Products#!/products/wave-usb---dealer-only---click-for-more-info");
}
        
if (x.toLowerCase() === "Waltz links".toLowerCase()) {
window.top.location = ("/Products#!/products/waltz-speaker-links");
}
        
if (x.toLowerCase() === "Waltz speakerlinks".toLowerCase()) {
window.top.location = ("/Products#!/products/waltz-speaker-links");
}
        
}            
        
</script>

</body>
```

Thank you for your time and stay safe.

Comment: it works for me, can you give us more information when it is not working as intended?

Comment: Hi Krzysztof, nothing more to expand on, other than it appears in the address bar, but doesn't load the product. 

I have noticed there are some products which say 'products' twice, but these load manually fine? Example

if (x.toLowerCase() === "Jet".toLowerCase()) {
            window.top.location = ("/Products#!/--hdmi/products/jet-hdmi---dealer-only---click-for-more-info");
            }

if (x.toLowerCase() === "Wave".toLowerCase()) {
            window.top.location = ("/Products#!/products/wave-usb---dealer-only---click-for-more-info");
            }

Comment: Hi there, I have moved my product container by 5px vertically, and it now works... annoying haha!

Comment: Okay, now it's back not working properly again...

Comment: No links are working on the left of www.black-rhodium.co.uk/products either.

Comment: If you are on the `/Products` URL already, then all you are doing there, is changing the _fragment_ portion of the URL - which does not cause a new request to the server by itself. If that is supposed to work, then you must have some sort of client-side router, that reacts on “hash changes”. Your question however contains too little information so far, for us to be able to tell what the actual situation is here.